# Fourier domain steganography for .mp4 video in python3

Tags: python-3.x, video, steganography

Well, one could say I got inspired by a project I saw on github made in rust that takes a .zip file and embeds it in a video that you could upload to youtube to have "file storage".

I wanted to do the same but in python and with Fourier domain steganography (not sure if that even works). I managed to use chatgpt (never doing that again, god it is awful now) to make a function that should (idk if it does) embed bytes from a .tar.gz file (or any file) into the video frames.

My main issues are that I don't know if it works. The code runs without error and it seems to work...but I don't know if it actually did embed the file bytes in the video. On top of that I don't know how to retrieve those file bytes that were supposedly embedded into the video frames. I am also unsure if the video being made via "generate_video()" has anything to do with any issues I may come across.

Here is some code that I have for context and that I am working on.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.fft import fft2, ifft2
import secrets
import string
import os
import tqdm

def clear():
    os.system('clear||cls')



# Generate a random file name using secrets and string libraries
def generate_filename():
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    filename = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(12)) + ".mp4"
    return filename


# Function to generate random visual noise/static
def generate_video():
    # Set video parameters
    width = 640
    height = 480
    fps = 30
    duration = 30


    # Create video writer object
    filename = generate_filename()
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, (width, height))

    # Write frames to the video
    for i in range(duration * fps):
        noise = np.random.randint(0, 256, (height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        out.write(noise)

    # Release the video writer and display filename
    out.release()
    return filename





def encode_video(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as rb:
        file_bytes = rb.read()

    video_path = generate_video()

    # Load video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    # Get video dimensions
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    num_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    # Calculate number of bytes to hide per frame
    bytes_per_frame = len(file_bytes) // num_frames

    # Create tqdm progress bar
    progress_bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=num_frames, desc="Embedding Data...")

    # Loop through video frames and hide bytes in each frame
    for i in range(num_frames):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            # Convert frame to grayscale
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Take the 2D fast Fourier transform of the grayscale frame
            fft = np.fft.fft2(gray)

            # Flatten the 2D Fourier transform into a 1D array
            fft_flat = fft.flatten()

            # Hide bytes in the Fourier coefficients
            start_index = i * bytes_per_frame
            end_index = start_index + bytes_per_frame
            bytes_to_hide = np.frombuffer(file_bytes[start_index:end_index], dtype=np.uint8)
            fft_flat[start_index:end_index] += bytes_to_hide

            # Reshape the modified Fourier coefficients back into a 2D array
            fft_modified = fft_flat.reshape(height, width)

            # Take the inverse Fourier transform to get the modified grayscale frame
            gray_modified = np.fft.ifft2(fft_modified).real

            # Convert the modified grayscale frame back to BGR color format
            frame_modified = cv2.cvtColor(gray_modified.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

            # Write the modified frame to the output video file
            if i == 0:
                # Create the VideoWriter object on the first iteration
                output_path = 'special_vid.mp4'
                fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
                out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, fps, (width, height), True)
            out.write(frame_modified)

            # Update progress bar
            progress_bar.update(1)

    progress_bar.close()

    # Release resources
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


    os.remove(video_path)
    os.rename(output_path, video_path)

    clear()
    print("Data successfully embedded.")
```

I don't have a function to extract the file bytes/data that was embedded in the first place. (yet..kinda hoping to get help with that too)

As for what I have tried, I couldn't find a place to start, searching things up didn't seem to help and all I got was definitions for steganography. I've also tried to use chatgpt like how I was able to get some sort of template to work off of like the "encode_video()" function...but that went about as well as one could expect...(didn't work). Everything it gave me just didn't seem to give me the correct bytes or data to write to a file.

For this question and why I have come to stack are the following

- To know if the "encode_video" function works and will even do what it's supposed to do.(hide/embed a file in the video)
- To get some help with a function to retrieve the embedded file from the video.

And if "Fourier domain steganography" will actually work, and if it doesn't, then some help on figuring out a different method for hiding a file in a video and retrieving the file.

Any advice, resources, or help would be VERY appreciated and loved.

---

TLDR; I am using "Fourier domain steganography" to try and hide a file in a video and idk if the function even works properly. I could use help with making a function to retrieve the file embedded into the video. And if this isn't possible, what other methods are there and can I get help with that as well.

(This is also the last time I even try to use chatgpt, but then again, I couldn't find any easily available resources covering what I wanted to do.)

Comment: It doesn't work, because saving frames to an mp4 passes them through the algorithm's compression algorithm which destroys your secret. That and the fact that it doesn't seem to be doing any real embedding, just adding values to the frames. Truncating floats to integers will also likely destroy your secret.

Comment: Aside from asking multiple questions and the what and how not being straightforward to explain (it boilds down to understanding the format you're trying to embed in), I suggest looking for artictles on google scholar, e.g. "(mp4|video|transform domain) steganography". Finally, the exraction is the exact reverse steps of the embedding, so once you understand that part, it's trivial to write the extracting algorithm. "It works" then just is `extract(embed(secret)) == secret`.